# RegExp to search for a string that contains substring '123' but does not contain substring '234'

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds

It is necessary to select rows from the table that contain one substring (or substrings) and do not contain others. It is important to make one expression.

Google says that regular expression like ^(?=.*subs1)(?!.*subs2)$ can work but it doesn't work for me (also tested on https://regexr.com/)

For example

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE target_string REGEXP "^(?=.*subs1)(?!.*subs2)$"
```

bla/subs1/bla/bla  -> true (return as query result)

bla/subs1/bla/subs2 -> false

bla/bla/subs2/bla -> false

2 conditions in one expression do not work (separately, work)
Thanks for help!

Comment: Should be `"^(?=.*subs1)(?!.*subs2).+$"` otherwise it only matches the empty string `^$` which will never match because of `(?=.*subs1)`.. you're welcome

Comment: https://regexr.com/4di5k, As @sin says, this works fine. Try with `^(?=.*subs1)(?!.*subs2)$.*`. You are missing on characters to match after your lookaheads.

Comment: Thanks for help. Its work but not in MySql 5.7.24 because it used standard POSIX 1003.2, which don't support using the question mark ? as a non-greedy (lazy) modifier to the star and plus quantifiers etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE foo     LIKE '%123%'
  AND foo NOT LIKE '%234%'

WHERE foo REGEXP '123[^4]'  -- rejects '1234', but accepts '123x234' -- OK?
```

(This should work in all versions of MySQL or MariaDB.)